# Google authentication in portable class library

Tags: c#, .net, windows, authentication, windows-phone-8

I write portable application for (WIndows Store, Windows Phone, Windows). I use portable class library.
I see that google make tasks api library for (WIndows Store, Windows Phone, Windows). But i have a problem with google auth.

This code does not work in portable library, (it's works on windows phone):

```
        private ObservableCollection<string> _tasklistTitlesCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> TasklistTitlesCollection
    {
        get { return _tasklistTitlesCollection; }
        set { _tasklistTitlesCollection = value; }
    }

    public async void MyFuncrion()
    {
        UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            //new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "", //"PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                ClientSecret = "" //"PUT_CLIENT_SECRETS_HERE"
            },
            new[] { TasksService.Scope.Tasks },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None);

        var service = new TasksService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Tasks API Sample",
        });

        TaskLists results = await service.Tasklists.List().ExecuteAsync();

        foreach (var tasklist in results.Items)
        {
            TasklistTitlesCollection.Add(tasklist.Title + " " + tasklist.Updated);
            // You can get data from the file (using file.Title for example)
            // and append it to a TextBox, List, etc.
        }
    }
```

1. I want to use this library for works with tasks/books, but
   I want to store UserCredential in windows conteiner with encryption(google store in app folder)
2. How i can crete `UserCredential credential` myself, without set return value from `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync`, I already have access code and want to past here?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can't without authenticating the user through google service

Comment: Ok. May i past here my access token/refresh/etc(i do it similar like in google). I want UserCredential credential = new UserCredential(access token/refresh/et)